# How to add multiple properties to Cloudflare Web Analytics?

Tags: analytics, cloudflare

I start using [Cloudflare Web Analytics](https://blog.cloudflare.com/privacy-first-web-analytics/) and I would like to add multiple properties in order to have analytics on multiple website but I couldn't find how.

Is there any limitation, or is that reserved to paying customers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update

It's now possible to add multiple properties to Cloudflare Web Analyitcs. Just go on the web analytics tab and click on "add site" on the right !

---

It's currently impossible to have multiple Cloudflare Web Analytics websites on the same account. They are going to fix that in the following weeks :

> At this time, you can only add analytics from one website to each Cloudflare account. In the coming weeks we’ll add support for multiple analytics properties per account.

See [Cloudflare’s privacy-first Web Analytics is now available for everyone](https://blog.cloudflare.com/privacy-first-web-analytics/) for more inforamtions.